# Get filesize with -s in Perl

Tags: perl, filesize

I am trying to find the size of a file using the `-s` operator. It looks like this:

```
my $filesz = -s $filename
```

I tried lots of various way, but it can not get this size.
However, if I give static content instead of filename, it works fine

For example:

```
$filesz = -s "/tmp/abc.txt"
```

This works fine.

I tried adding `"` in the filename, it didn't work. I removed `\n` from filename using `chomp`, but the problem remains the same. What's wrong here?

Comment: `-s $filename if -e $filename`

Comment: Did you ever print out the contents of `$filename` to see if it's what you think it is?

Comment: @Ether: I did .. its just that it was \n which was not easily visible :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`-s $filename` works just fine; the only conclusion is that there's no file with the name contained in `$filename`. Take a very close look at the contents of `$filename`, and make sure that your working directory is what you think it is.

Comment: There were two issues
1. There was \n which was not getting chomped properly. It was not visible with print

2. I was adding " character around path which was not working with -s.

Comment: @Jack Sounds like your problem was actually with `\r`, not `\n` (and your problem would have been solved by the `:crlf` I/O layer, which translates between `\r\n` and `\n`). Anyway, glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

[As hobbs says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560099/perl-get-filesize-with-s/3560153#3560153), the most likely explanation is that `$filename` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Based on previous experience, I'd go further than that and hesitate a guess that `$filename` has a newline character at the end of it. Are you reading the value in `$filename` from a file or from user input?

Comment: yes, that was one of the issue. I was getting filename from readdir loop.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try this your getting from a readdir:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filedir = "/documents/sample/file.txt";


opendir(my $dir, $filedir) or die "Could not load directory";
my @read_dir = sort grep {!-d}readdir($dir);
foreach my $fileInDir(@read_dir)
{

    my $currentDestination = "$filedir/$fileInDir";
    my $filesize = -s $currentDestination;

    if(-z $currentDestination)
    {
       print "Zero -  Filename: $fileInDir Size: $filesize\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "Non - Zero Filename: $fileInDir Size: $filesize\n";
    }

}
```